# Mac Mini startup sound always plays on internal speaker

Tags: macos, audio, system-settings

My 2012 Mac Mini (Mavericks) is plugged into a USB audio interface which is selected as my sound in and sound out device. All works great, except for the startup sound which still comes out of the internal speaker. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Interestingly, I love that it no longer comes from any plugged-in speaker system... because when it does, it's *damn* loud. It may be connected to where you have System Prefs > Sound > Sound Effects set to play through; I have mine set to run all beeps through the internal speakers - for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly this is a feature and you can't change it. Other Mac have the same problem. You juste can mute the sound of the internal speaker during the boot.

https://superuser.com/questions/770364/why-does-my-macbook-play-the-startup-sound-through-the-speakers-rather-than-thro

Answer (score 1):

When the computer is first powered on and before the OS has started, it plays a system sound (a "bong") to let you know the computer is starting.

The problem is that at that point, the computer has no access to your USB audio device, since it would require that the OS be loaded with a device driver for that device, in order to use it to play a sound.

I believe that if you plug headphones or speakers into the Mac Mini's headphones socket then you will hear the bong through the headphones/speakers, but any audio device that requires a driver in order to work (including all USB audio devices), will not be able to play the bong.

Comment: Ah, so if I plug in via line-out rather than USB the problem would go away? Can I control the volume levels independently so that before it recognises USB, the internal speaker volume is very low/off?

Comment: According to the other answer (follow the link http://superuser.com/questions/770364/why-does-my-macbook-play-the-startup-sound-through-the-speakers-rather-than-thro), apparently you can.